# Does the swfjunkie Tweetr library actually still works?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, twitter, air

I need to add twitter integration into an AIR for Android application and I've found the http://wiki.swfjunkie.com/tweetr library.

But, none of the examples given on the site seems to work... http://wiki.swfjunkie.com/tweetr:examples

Is this library still  compatible with today's twitter API ?

Why are the examples not displaying any tweet ?

What would you recommend for adding timeline display and send tweet functionnality to an AIR for Android application ?

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: @RaghavSood Flash support, yes, but not AIR support. Adobe is still going full steam with AIR.

Answer (score 0):

The Twittter API has changed in recent months, and I actually had to refactor some code in my apps to deal with it. Unless this library is updated, it won't work. Here's more information: http://mashable.com/2012/09/05/twitter-api-rss/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lostPixels ! I still have two questions : first, I've realized that tweetr uses the Twitter REST 1.0 API. Do you think this API will still work for a long time ? And second, what do you use in your AS3 project to query and post tweets ? Any suggested lib ?

Comment: Howdy there. I believe that API is depreciated. I was tapping into Twitter from an AIR app, and I had to deal with XMl Namespaces which are a pain in the ass. You receive data from a URL like this: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=tothepixel, and then parse it with namespaces like this: twitterXML.atom::entry[0] . It's a little more complex than that, but there are plenty of tutorials online. I would suggest building your own custom solution honestly.